# List contents of floppy image file without mounting in Linux

Tags: linux, image, dos, floppy

I have a huge pile of old (DOS, probably FAT12) floppy image files which I'd like to browse quickly, without having to loop-mount each of them first. Something like Midnight Commander's "iso9660://" virtual file system, just for floppy images.

How can I quickly get a list of files on these images, or perhaps even open these images as (readonly) archives?

Comment: [Mtools](https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/) is a collection of utilities to access MS-DOS disks from GNU and Unix without mounting them.

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. It seems mc's VFS support relies on configuration files in /usr/lib/mc/extfs.d/ where you have to put a script with functions that list files, copy out files, copy in files, make directores etc. inside your image file.
Mtools would probably fit this bill, I'll just have to write the functions to output in the right format.